# Reading numbers from a file into an array

Tags: c, arrays, text-files, fgetc

I would like to read 3-digit-numbers with spaces inbetween from a file with the fgetc()-command and put them into an array, which is not currently working, as the resulting array has completely different objects in it. What am I doing wrong? (I used a file with "107 313 052 614" in it, resulting in the output "5435 5641 5380 5942")

My Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


void print_array(int* arrayp, int lengthp){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<lengthp;i++){
        printf("%i ", arrayp[i]);
    }
    return;
}

int main(){
    int length=1;
    int i;
    FILE *fp1;
    fp1 = fopen("durations.txt", "r");
    fgetc(fp1);fgetc(fp1);fgetc(fp1);
    while(fgetc(fp1)!=EOF){
        length++;
        fgetc(fp1);
        fgetc(fp1);
        fgetc(fp1);
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    int* list = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    FILE *fp2;
    fp2 = fopen("durations.txt", "r");
    for(i=0;i<length;i++){
        list[i]=0;
        list[i]+=100*(fgetc(fp2));
        list[i]+=10*(fgetc(fp2));
        list[i]+=(fgetc(fp2));
        fgetc(fp2);
    }
    fclose(fp2);
    print_array(list, length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The characters used to store digits are not numbers. They are encoded most probably using a ascii encoding.

Comment: look into fscanf, you use it exactly like printf and sprintf with a string that specifies the format so in your case for integers the format would be "%d %d %d", then pass the address of each item &list[0], &list[1], &list[2], the first parameter before the format is the file pointer.  It works fine in C:  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characters that are used to store digits in a "readable" file are not "numbers". The most popular encoding is [ascii character encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), ex. the `1` digit is represented with the number 49 in decimal.

Because the 0, 1, 2 ... 9 digits in ascii encoding are encoded in increasing order, you can just substract 48 (ie. `'0'` character) to convert a digit character to it's machine format Just `- '0'`.

Change you loop into:

```
for(i=0;i<length;i++){
    list[i]=0;
    list[i]+=100*(fgetc(fp2) - '0');
    list[i]+=10*(fgetc(fp2) - '0');
    list[i]+=(fgetc(fp2) - '0');
    fgetc(fp2);
}
```

This also explains the current output of your program. If you don't substract `'0'` from the numbers, then for example for `107` you get:

```
100 * '1' + 10 * '0' + '7' =
100 * 49  + 10 * 48  + 55  =
5435
```

The `49`, `48` and `55` are decimal values for digits `1`, `0` and `7` in ascii table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your are reading in the (probably) `ASCII` values of each digit and assuming that is the value of the digit. You need to subtract the value of the zero character from each value, like this:

```c
for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    list[i] = 0;
    list[i] += 100 * (fgetc(fp2)-'0');
    list[i] += 10 * (fgetc(fp2)-'0');
    list[i] += (fgetc(fp2)-'0');
    fgetc(fp2);
}
```

This will work even if your system doesn't use `ASCII` encoding.

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to just read the numbers into cstrings then use the stdlib function atoi to convert each string to a number before loading into the array of ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {

    //open the file for reading with error checking:
    FILE* fp;
    char c = '0';
    int length = 0;
    fp = fopen("durations.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //count the number of lines in a EOF-terminated string w/o newlines
    for (c = fgetc(fp); c != EOF; c = fgetc(fp)) {
            if (c == ' ') {
                length += 1;
            }
        }
    rewind(fp);    //go back to file end w/o needing close/open 

    //Then, assuming only spaces are between numbers (so length = length + 1)
    char buffer[4];
    int* lst = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {
        fscanf(fp, "%s", buffer);  //stops at spaces
        lst[i] = atoi(buffer);
        }

    //close the file with error checking
    int check = fclose(fp);
    if (check != 0) {
        printf("File close failed");
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < length + 1; i++) {   //print result
        printf("%d\n", lst[i]);
    }

    free(lst);       //clean up memory after use
    lst = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```